# Missing Plugin Exception No Implementation found for method flutter android

Tags: android, flutter

i am using a plugin contacts service to read & write contacts on the phone
but a weird message keeps coming up every time I try to fetch the contacts the message says

```
1)W/FlutterEnginePluginRegistry: Attempted to register plugin (flutter.plugins.contactsservice.contactsservice.ContactsServicePlugin@1a29818) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@7224271).

2)MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getContacts on channel github.com/clovisnicolas/flutter_contacts)
```

My Main Activity.java File is

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new FlutterEngine(this));
    ctx = this;
    instance = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FlutterView view = getFlutterView();
    new MethodChannel(view,CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
            if(call.method.equals("callMazay"))
            {
                String respo=connectMazay(this);
                System.out.print("came Here");
                result.success(respo);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and my flutter code is

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
 class _ContactsScreenState extends State<ContactsScreen> {
 List<Contact> contacts = [];
 List<Contact> contactsFiltered = [];
 Map<String, Color> contactsColorMap = new Map();
 TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
getAllContacts();
}

getAllContacts() async {
try{
List<Contact> _contacts = (await ContactsService.getContacts()).toList();
_contacts.forEach((contact) {
  print(contact);
});
}
catch(e)
{
  print(e);
}
}//getall

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Text('Hello'),
);
}

}
```

Comment: post full code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [THIS](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Experimental:-Use-old-plugins-with-new-embedding) , you need to override configureFlutterEngine, for example:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }
```

GetContact method in flutter code (this is a +)

```
getContacts() async {
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var contacts = await ContactsService.getContacts();
      setState(() {
        _contacts = contacts;
        print("Contact List "+contacts.toList().toString());
      });
    } else {
      print("Contact List: Permission denied ");
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
        message: 'Access to location data denied',
        details: null,
      );
    }
  }
```